# OS killed some of databse demons

Tags: db2, centos, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I have 2 HP servers with CntOS 6 as OS and DB2 10.5 as Database. there 2 servers are HADR. standby server suddenly rebooted and when i checked log it said that OS had killed 4 db2 demons.

1. IBM.ConfigRM
2. ctcasd
3. RMCD_INFO_1_ST
4. GS_STOP_ST

why this happens? why OS killed these demons?
there is no explaination in diag or other log file to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen due to exhausted virtual memory on your server. OOM killer kills processes to free some memory in this case.

You can try to collect some information next time when it happens again with `db2fodc -detect` functionality using either predefined script or your own.

See the `Threshold collection examples` at the [db2fodc - DB2 first occurrence data collection command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0051934.html) link.

Comment: if it was because of VM it could see it diag file. i saw it before. and i checked its memory state before reboot (by a monitoring tool) it had 70% free memory